# iOS 11.2 - Search Controller Bar background is clear when inside Navigation Bar with Large Title

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, ios11.2

so I just updated to iOS 11.2, and now my `UISearchController`'s search bar is messed up. When search is active, the background behind the search bar area goes invisible / clear / transparent.

I built a test project to make sure I wasn't crazy. Here's the original setup:

```
navigationBar.translucent = YES;
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

self.navigationItem.searchController = myUISearchController;
```

**Here's how it should appear:**

[image: With <code>prefersLargeTitles</code> off]

---

## But if I use large titles and a background image, then the result is this:

```
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:bgImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image: With <code>prefersLargeTitles</code> on]

---

If anyone finds a solution to this, I'd really appreciate the help.

## ✌️

Comment: Same happening to me. Since you already did a test project, fill a radar with it :)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from just bailing on the background image or large title, here's the only solution I've come up with.

Disable large titles before search appears, and enable it again when it dismisses. Kind of sucks but seems to do the trick.

```
self.navigationItem.searchController.delegate = self;

...

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = NO;
}

- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
}
```